# How do I math code Product symbol other than type $\prod_{i=1}^{n}$

Tags: math-operators, mathjax

I can code symbols of the type $$\prod_{i=1}^{n}$$ 
but when it comes to:
[image]

I cannot get the less-than-equal sign placed as shown.Can this be done easily?

EDIT: below removed as reason explained in the comments 
**not sure why $\prod_{i=1}^{n}$ not displaying properly while in math.stackexchange its fine*

Comment: See also [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths) and definitely look at [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)

Comment: @Henri Menke  thanks for the resources will look through them. Its just most people in math.stackexchange write it like I showed it thats why I could not find an example to work out how to do it!

Comment: Try `\prod_{p\le 7}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)` as a starting point. Note that this will come out different when it is displayed `\[..\]` vs. inline `$..$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's for in-line mathematics, you can use

```
$\prod\limits_{i\le 7}$,
```

but be aware this may slightly increase the vertical spacing with the line  below.

Answer (score 3):

Have you even tried it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[ \prod_{p \leq 7} \biggl( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \biggr) \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: okay thanks that did the trick. $ \prod_{p \leq 7} \biggl( 1 - \frac{1}{p} \biggr) $ particulary in math.stackexchange not that I need it elsewhere.